# How to work correctly with localstorage in Next Js 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, zustand

Next Js 14

I want to implement storage of products added to the cart using **localStorage**.

I'm using this approach now:

1. Create LocalStorage component, and insert data from localstore to zustand store
2. Use  on top level in page

```js
"use client";

import { useAddBasket } from "@/shared/hooks";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const LocalStorage = () => {
  const { init } = useAddBasket(); // zustand store
  useEffect(() => {
    const storage = localStorage.getItem("basket");
    if (storage) {
      const products = JSON.parse(storage);
      init(products);
    }

  }, []);

  return <></>;

};
```

In this case I avoid mistakes **ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined** but i think this is the wrong approach.

Another problem is that some data, such as the number of products in the cart, is 0 when updating the page, and becomes correct only after init() function is processed.

How can I improve the experience with localStorage?

Comment: Since you are using localStorage, There's no way to handle it on the server side. I would recommend using cookies instead to support SSR. but if you still want to stick with localStorage then you should handle it client side and to avoid showing 0 before the value is set. You should have conditional rendering and show loading before the value is set.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the window its not working properly.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const storage = localStorage.getItem("basket");
    if (storage) {
      const products = JSON.parse(storage);
      init(products);
    }
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: no my code is working
the question is different: Is there a way to work with localstorage more concisely in next